# Ubuntu Servers and Support Pricing

Tags: server, canonical

What is the pricing of an Ubuntu Servers per server per year and what is the price for the support?

Comment: @waltinator: I think OP is asking about Canonical's paid support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu as an OS is freely available.

Canonical offers professional support. See http://www.canonical.com/services and https://www.ubuntu.com/support/plans-and-pricing

Sort of depends on what sort of service and support you are needing, but you really need to contact Canonical as AskUbuntu is volunteer supported and not operated by Canonical.